# Python changing hour-minute to hour ending format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
df
    DateTime    Qty
1/1/2018 0:00    0.6 
1/1/2018 0:15    0.6 
1/1/2018 0:30    0.4 
1/1/2018 0:45    0.5 
1/1/2018 1:00    1.0 
1/1/2018 1:15    0.2 
1/1/2018 1:30    0.2 
1/1/2018 1:45    0.5 
1/1/2018 1:45    0.0 
1/1/2018 2:00    0.3
```

I want to change the data above to:

```
df
DateTime         Qty    DateTime2
1/1/2018 0:00    0.6    1/1/2018 0:00
1/1/2018 0:15    0.6    1/1/2018 1:00
1/1/2018 0:30    0.4    1/1/2018 1:00
1/1/2018 0:45    0.5    1/1/2018 1:00
1/1/2018 1:00    1.0    1/1/2018 1:00
1/1/2018 1:15    0.2    1/1/2018 2:00
1/1/2018 1:30    0.2    1/1/2018 2:00
1/1/2018 1:45    0.5    1/1/2018 2:00
1/1/2018 1:45    0.0    1/1/2018 2:00
1/1/2018 2:00    0.3    1/1/2018 2:00
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this. The solution I have is to get minutes and when it is greater than 15, add an hour to the datetime hour

My solution:

```
df['hrAdder'] = np.where(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime2'].values).minute >= 15., 1, 0)
df['DateTime3'] = df['DateTime2'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['hrAdder'], unit='h')
```

Comment: Can you post the solution you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)
df['DateTime2'] = df.DateTime
condition = df.DateTime2.dt.minute >= 15
```

**`dt.ceil`** with **`loc`**

```
df.loc[condition, 'DateTime2'] = df[condition].DateTime2.dt.ceil(freq='H')

# Result

             DateTime  Qty           DateTime2
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.6 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1 2018-01-01 00:15:00  0.6 2018-01-01 01:00:00
2 2018-01-01 00:30:00  0.4 2018-01-01 01:00:00
3 2018-01-01 00:45:00  0.5 2018-01-01 01:00:00
4 2018-01-01 01:00:00  1.0 2018-01-01 01:00:00
5 2018-01-01 01:15:00  0.2 2018-01-01 02:00:00
6 2018-01-01 01:30:00  0.2 2018-01-01 02:00:00
7 2018-01-01 01:45:00  0.5 2018-01-01 02:00:00
8 2018-01-01 01:45:00  0.0 2018-01-01 02:00:00
9 2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.3 2018-01-01 02:00:00
```